# I think it should contain different lists for each "append" but it is not

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

after I run this little piece of code, it would always return a list that contains exactly same smaller lists...

```
import time
from random import randint

t = [0,0]
a = []

def rec():
    a.append(t)

for i in range(10):
    t[0] = randint(10,20)
    t[1] = randint(40,500)
    rec()
    time.sleep(.0001)

print a
```

I get something like this as output, why?

```
[[17, 134], [17, 134], [17, 134], [17, 134], [17, 134], [17, 134], [17, 134], [17, 134], [17, 134], [17, 134]]
```

Comment: You're reusing the list pointed to by `t`.

Comment: You could say `a.append(list(t))` which will make a copy of `t` first.

Comment: What do you want to get?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python

Comment: You append the **same** list everytime, `t` is always the same list, changing the list will change the list wherever that same list exists. Assignment, sending as a parameter to a function or returning just means that you get another name for the same object.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the wacky world of mutable vs immutable types!

The short of it is that in Python list's are mutable, meaning references to lists will actually change the original list! You will have to create a new list  by doing `t = [randint(10,20), randint(40,500)]`. That should do the trick for you :)

For more information on mutable vs immutable types refer to [this SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types-python)!

I would also recommend not having functions like `rec`. Try to avoid using globals when you do not need them (they make debugging more difficult than it needs to be). Why not just pass in a parameter? Or just use `append` inline!

Comment: But you need to declare it `global` first, otherwise it will just be a local list and won't be the one appended by `rec`.

Comment: But `t` was already declared in the global scope! The OPs code with my suggestion added works for me :)

Comment: thanks! Well because I am using a decorator to limit the speed that rec() runs, so I need to define a function there...

Answer (score 0):

How about using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) - `[[randint(10,20), randint(40,500)] for i in range(10)]`?